# Copy from excel and paste in grid in angular 2

Tags: javascript, datagrid, angular2-directives

I would like to implement copy functionality like below.

1. Select a row from excel and copy
2. And in the front-end UI we should be able to paste the selected data in a grid

Comment: You're confused on which point ? What did you tried ?

Comment: I am not able to understand how to implement this functionality.It would be really helpful if dome samples can be provided

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you, we need a bit more context. Please edit your question to include a [MCVE].

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following implementation of a JavaScript grid in Angular 2 - ng2-handsontable:

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-handsontable

Here you can see a working demo:

http://valor-software.com/ng2-handsontable/

Comment: Hey, do you know if this library is free to commercial use? I know handsontable js is not free and this library is MIT license.